# Deleting an older bot message after sending Python Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

My bot is a 'nightmode' bot that starts at 10pm and ends at 7am, it will delete the messages in between those. I'm trying to delete the previous nightmode message sent from the bot but unsure how to go about this, I thought about storing the previous message update and then adding 1 to it and storing that, but I'm not sure how to go about this if the bot is running in multiple groups. Here's my code:

```
import logging
from telegram import Update, ForceReply
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackContext, Handler
import datetime as dtm
import pytz
night_hours = ['22','23','00','01','02','03','04','05','06']
allowed_groups = ['GROUP ID 1','GROUP ID 2','GROUP ID 3']

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def error(update, context):
    """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)

def start(context: CallbackContext):
    morning_time = dtm.time(hour=7, minute=0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/London'))
    evening_time = dtm.time(hour=22, minute=0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/London'))
    context.job_queue.run_daily(morning_message, morning_time)
    context.job_queue.run_daily(night_message, evening_time)

def log_channel(context: CallbackContext,name,chat_name,message):

    deleted_message = ("Message Deleted from *" +name+ "* in the group *'" +chat_name+ "'*: " +message)
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id="LOG CHANNEL ID", text=deleted_message,
                             disable_notification=True, parse_mode="MARKDOWNV2")
    print(deleted_message)

def morning_message(context: CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id="TEST GROUP ID",text="*NIGHT MODE END:*\n\nMessage sending enabled until 10PM",
                             disable_notification=True,parse_mode="MARKDOWNV2")

def night_message(context: CallbackContext):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id="TEST GROUP ID", text="*NIGHT MODE START:*\n\nMessage sending disabled until 7AM",
                             disable_notification=True,parse_mode="MARKDOWNV2")

def during_night_mode(update: Update,context: CallbackContext):
    UK = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
    uk_time = dtm.datetime.now(UK).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    hour = dtm.datetime.now(UK).strftime('%H')
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id
    chat_name = update.message.chat.title
    message_id = update.message.message_id
    print(chat_id)
    print(message_id)
    incoming_text = str(update.message.text)
    incoming_entities = update.message.entities #images, videos, files etc... probably not gonna use.
    message_sender = str(update.message.from_user.first_name)
    print(hour)
    if str(hour) in night_hours and str(chat_id) in allowed_groups: # and Enabled == True
        print("working")
        context.bot.delete_message(chat_id,message_id)
        log_channel(context,message_sender,chat_name,incoming_text)

def main() -> None:
    """Start the bot."""
    updater = Updater("BOT KEY")
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    #dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))#, pass_job_queue=True))
    #dp.add_handler(CommandHandler(start))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.all,during_night_mode))
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()
    start(dp)
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks

EDIT 1:
Basically, i only want 1 instance of the night mode message in the chat at all times. So for example, when the morning message runs, it will delete the previous night time message so it does not clutter the chat with the messages.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do but probably `send_message` should give you message's ID - `message_id = send_message(...)` - and you can use this ID to delete message

Comment: is it actually that simple? I'll try that now. i'll edit the post to explain more what i'm trying to do!

Comment: doc for [send_message](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_message) shows `"Returns: On success, the sent message is returned."` So it gives not only ID but full object [Message](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message) with all information - `message_id`, `chat`, etc. - so you can save all (ie. using `pickle`) or only needed values and later you can use it to delete this message.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for [send_message()](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_message) shows

```
Returns: On success, the sent message is returned.

Return type: telegram.Message
```

So you can run

```
msg = context.bot.send_message(...)
```

to get all information about sent [Message](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message)  - `message_id`, `chat`, etc. - and save all (ie. using `pickle`) or only needed values (ie. using text file, `json`, etc.) or keep on some list (if you run code all time) and later you can use it to delete message(s).